# Java - Convert List<Number> to List<Integer>?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I'm a bit confused about how Java generics handle inheritance / polymorphism.
It's fully possible to classcast Number to Integer but it seams not possible to classcast `List<Number>` to `List<Integer>`.
Why ?

Here is my java code sample :

```
    Number n = new Integer(5);
    Integer i = (Integer) n; // No compilation or runtime error ==> for me it's normal

    Number n = new Long(5);
    Integer i = (Integer) n; // No compilation error but have a runtime error (ClassCastException) ==> for me it's normal

    List<Number> nList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    nList.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
    List<Integer> iList = (List <Integer>) nList; // Compilation error ==> WHYYYY ?!!
```

Thank's for your help.

**EDIT** :
This question is completely different from this one [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) because my question is not why it's mandatory to write the class cast.

To be more specific, I call a function that returns a `List<Change>` where `Change` is an abstract super class so this list can contain `ChangeItem` or `ChangeList` or whatever subclass of `Change` depending on my request (parameters).

I know my request makes this function returning only `ChangeItem` so I want to convert it easily to return it from my function. I was thinking a class cast was the simplest way to do but it seems not possible because of compilation error.

Why it's possible to write and compil this :

```
    Number n = new Long(5);
    Integer i = (Integer) n;
```

While it's impossible to write and compil this :

```
    List<Number> nList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    nList.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
    List<Integer> iList = (List <Integer>) nList;
```

I just want the same ClassCastException if nList contains other things than Integer.

Comment: Why? Because the compiler can't prove that you didn't write `nList.add(Double.valueOf(5));` before the cast.

Comment: It's actually more like: Because the compiler *can* prove that `List<Integer>` is incompatible with `List<Number>`, i.e. `List<Integer>` cannot possibly also be a `List<Number>`, similar to how `String s = (String) n` is a compilation error, because a `Number` cannot possibly also be a `String`.

Comment: ... and if you did add a Double, you'll eventually get a ClassCastException, but it could be far away from the code in your snippet, and it'll look weird. You'll have something like `List<Integer> myList = whatever(); Integer i = myList.get(0);` saying that a Double can't be converted to Integer -- classic recipe for a "huh?". The ClassCastException will be confusing, and the actual site of the problem (the `nList.add(Double.valueOf(5))`) will be hard to track down.